# A List of List and Object

Tags: c#, arraylist

I want a List of OtherObjects all belonging to certain Objects.
Is it possible to create a List like so?

```
List<Object, List<OtherObject>>
```

Or should I create a new class and do?

```
List<NewClass>
```

Or should I do something else overall? The size is dynamic so I didn't want to use an array.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: List takes only one parameter in template: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: @AlcariTheMad I don't understand why I have to answer such questions. But if you really want to know, I want a List of `OtherObject`s all belonging to certain `Object`s. Thats not a weird question is it? Like I want the list of snacks every child wants in my group...

Comment: Your original question didn't say that. DaveDev's answer solves your problem, though.

Comment: Are you want to get `Dictionary` of `Dictionary`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: @Joetjah: You have to answer such a question, because depending on the answer we might suggest different solutions.

Comment: @AlcariTheMad I knew it wasn't possible in normal `List`s, that's why I asked like this. `Dictionary` suites my needs. Thank you all for thinking with me :)

Comment: @AlcariTheMad Also, I responded like that because people tend to not reply to questions if it sounds silly to them.. Like asking how the method `x.Add()` works, and people replying with "Why do you want to know?"

Comment: @Joetjah: People ask that, because such a question really is too vague. Depending on why you want to know that, the answerer can concentrate on that specific area of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a Dictionary<>, e.g.

```
Dictionary<Object, List<OtherObject>>
```

Where `Object` is the Key and `List<OtherObject>` is the Value

Comment: Dictionary class with an object key is not a good idea in general. The only Dictionary behaviour needed is IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<>> interface, so the List of KeyValuePairs should be enough.

Comment: Is it good idea to store object as key in dictionary. Just for Knowlegde How dictionary will come to know for any duplicate Key

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Tuple<Object, List<OtherObject>>` to achieve what you want.

Tuples is for composition of properties when you don't want to create special class. You can use `Tuple<Object, AnotherObject, AnotherAnotherObject>` if you need.

Your code will be something like:

```
List<Tuple<Object, List<OtherObject>>> list;
```

and work with it:

```
foreach(var tuple in list)
{
   var object = tuple.Item1;
   var innerList = tuple.Item2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try Using

`Dictionary<Object, List<OtherObject>>`

Hope i helped

Comment: ohh sorry . . i will delete this comment . . and i didnt copy the answer. its just that my internet connection is slow. .didnt refresh immediately . My Apologies